# Question About mmPrtrain config option "--auto-scale-lr"

Tags: python

I don't exactly understand about `--auto-scale-lr`.
If I have a batch size of 4096 trained in paper,
and my machine only supports a batch size of 64,
If I use this option, will the lr schedule adjustment be done after 64 steps (4096//64)?
If I want to use this,
Do I need to call `--auto-scale-lr` when calling train.py
from cmd in addition to what I define in config.py?

To summarize my question.

what exactly is `auto-scale-lr` for?
do I need cmd and config.py to utilize auto-scale-lr?
(Or does it run automatically if it's in .py)
it using like gradient accumlation?